# VMWare tools on Ubuntu Server 10.10 kernel source problem

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, open-source, vmware-tools

After install and running the vm-ware config, the config needs my kernel headers to compile some modules, ok, so I'll give it them, but it just won't work.

It asks for the path of the directory of C header files that match my running kernel.

If I

`uname -r`

I get

```
2.6.35-22-generic-pae
```

So I tell it the source path is

`/lib/modules/2.6.25-22-generic-pae/build/include`

and it returns

`"The directory of kernel headers (version @@VMWARE@@ UTS_RELEASE) does not match your running kernel (version 2.6.35-22-generic-pae).`

..I'm confused? can anyone offer suggestions please?

I installed hte kernel source andh eaders myself using

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Ok, I found a solution that is working. Aparently this is to do with the UTS_RELEASE "define" not being found in the version.h, but I couldn't get it to compile with this. Instead I simply installed open-vm-tools from the ubuntu universe repo and it works fine now. Problem solved (in an alternative sort of way).

Comment: But below you say you did something with open-vm-source. Can you give us a step-by-step? It's not clear to me how you fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing [open-vm-source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/open-vm-source) and install the kernel modules with DKMS.

Comment: As mentioned above I found a solution, I tried to build the .debs from the open-vm-source and it installed correctly (as far as I could see) but it did not function ideally, so I removed them and installed from the software-center the opensource version.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add the line

```
#define UTS_RELEASE "<your kernel version, e.g 2.6.35-25-server>"
```

to `/usr/src/linux-headers-<your kernel version>/include/linux/version.h` and copy the file `/usr/src/linux-headers-<your kernel version>/include/generated/autoconf.h` to `/usr/src/linux-headers-<your kernel version>/include/linux/`.